# Why don't these functions decay to a function pointer?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, closures

I had a class which held a function pointer to be called, and now I've come across a situation where I would like that callable function to hold a self-contained reference/value (lambda). So I create my templated class to accept either function pointers or lambdas like this:

```
template <typename FunctionType>
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(FunctionType function) : function(function) {}
    FunctionType function;
};
```

However it seems that each each time that this class is instantiated the compiler creates a different 'type' of class, as shown below:

```
int main()
{
    MyClass foo([]() {return 5; });
    MyClass foo2([]() {return 5; });
    MyClass foo3([]() {return 5; }); // ALL THREE OF THESE SEEM TO BE DIFFERENT TYPES
    MyClass foo4(static_cast<int(*)()> ([]() {return 5; })); // I THINK I CAN FORCE THEM TO BE THE SAME TYPES BY CASTING
    MyClass foo5(static_cast<int(*)()> ([]() {return 5; }));
    MyClass foo6(static_cast<int(*)()> ([]() {return 5; }));

    std::cout << typeid(foo).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(foo2).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(foo3).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(foo4).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(foo5).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(foo6).name() << '\n';
}
```

The output from this is:

```
class MyClass<class <lambda_e39b14fd1b959adc3c33a259b5258211> >
class MyClass<class <lambda_de164f9f0bca248459ade49332a364c3> >
class MyClass<class <lambda_9fcf071b66983e924cb117ca1e77c4c6> >
class MyClass<int (__cdecl*)(void)>
class MyClass<int (__cdecl*)(void)>
class MyClass<int (__cdecl*)(void)>
```

As I'll be creating hundreds or thousands of these I'd like for this not to be the case if at all possible. Most functions I'll pass to my class should be of the same type except for the occasional different lambda that I'll be needing. So is it the case the compiler is creating a different type every time I pass the same function type? It doesn't seem very efficient if that's the case. If it must be the case what's the best way to reduce the number of class types the compiler creates? I think I achieved it by casting to function pointer at the creation of the class, but this seems like a terrible way of doing it.

Comment: Is the question about _decay/usage_ or about _different types_ (and potential reduction of such)? The body of the posts appears to stray from the title.

Comment: Actually, it is ***required*** that each lambda is its own unique anonymous class.

Comment: `It doesn't seem very efficient if that's the case.` different types does not necessarily mean that the compiler creates distinct code for it.

Comment: @user2864740 How can I avoid having the compiler create another class type every time I create a new instance of that class.

Comment: Do those functions differ in their signature? Or are they always in the form (`int ()`)

Comment: @Zebrafish In that case, the title might be more along the lines of: "Is there a way to avoid creating a new class/type for identical lambdas?" (or some such).

Comment: Are you avoiding `std::function<int()>` intentionally?

Comment: Note that with `std::function`, your `MyClass` even does not need to be a template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make your class store a function pointer instead, like this:

```
template <typename Ret, typename ...Args>
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(Ret (*function)(Args...)) : function(function) {}
    Ret (*function)(Args...);
};
```

Then you can store the lambda, by explicitly decaying it to a function pointer:

```
MyClass foo( + []() {return 5; });
```

and then only one class will be instantiated per function signature (whether it's a lambda or a function).

Here's a [demo](https://www.godbolt.org/z/QKQLgF).

Comment: What does the + mean before the lambda?

Comment: It's a "trick" (technique) to decay a lambda into a function pointer. If you don't do that, the argument deduction will fail.

Comment: Ahhh, I see, that + trick is exactly what I'm looking for, nice little touch. It'll be interesting to see what happens when I use it on something that's not decayable to a pointer, there's a question on here about it I'm reading it now.

Comment: Isn't that pointer stored in the class _dangling_ after the constructor has finished? Where is the pointed-to lambda object stored?

Comment: @DanielLangr there is no object as the Lambda has no state, if there was state then the lambda wouldn't be convertible to a function pointer

Comment: @AlanBirtles So [these lambdas with state](https://www.godbolt.org/z/szmKTN) will be dangling? (the first two) They are not mutating though ...

Comment: To be more precise they aren't capturing anything, Ted's examples aren't capturing so though they have state that state isn't stored in the lambda itself, its stored in static variables, e.g. this https://www.godbolt.org/z/f9dmeh doesn't print 0 both times

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks. I just ran [this](https://www.godbolt.org/z/i3Teyo) through valgrind to check - and it was fine :-) Capturing / mutating is out. Got it... Edit: It can be declared `mutable` but as long as it's not trying to mutate, it seems to be fine.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Cppinsights might help here: https://cppinsights.io/s/5ad75317.

Comment: @DanielLangr It's very nice to be able to see the lambda class instantiations at cppinsights but I'm not sure what I should be looking for in this case?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I meant that it shows that there is no dangling pointer. But, in fact, now I think that Cppinsinghts is wrong with this case, since it shows two independent static `foo`. However, there should be only one (likely implemented as a static member variable of the lambda class). Calling lambda's function-call operator as well as function pointer works with the same `foo`: https://godbolt.org/z/uEw2T8, which does not correspond with Cppinsights.

Comment: @DanielLangr Aha, ok. It'll always be different lambda classes (and therefore independen `foo`s) but you can point the lambdas out with same function pointer type. In your example your are _pointing_ at the lambda instance, so it's the same lambda, hence the same static variable.

Comment: @TedLyngmo My point was that Cppinsight showed two independent `foo` even for a single lambda, which, IMO, is incorrect.

Comment: @DanielLangr Aha, now I see your point! Yes, there's one sneaky one in the `private` `__invoke()` method too. I wonder who's using that? :-)